# Grabbing contact information with python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab the contact information from a page.  I need the name, job title, phone, and email address.

I'm learning Python and trying to write code against data I know.  I was able to pull out the div blocks with the individual contacts, but I'm not sure how to crawl through them once I have them.

```py
tags = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'tshowcase-inner-box'})
```

but then I wanted to crawl through the children divs and had no luck.

```py
    fullname = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'tshowcase-box-title'})
    title = soup('div', attrs={'class':'tshowcase-single-position'})
    phone = soup('div', attrs={'class':'tshowcase-single-telephone'})
    email = soup('div', attrs={'class':'tshowcase-box-social'})
```

I'm not sure what's next though and appreciate any pointers.

Here is the sample HTML:

```html
<div class="tshowcase-inner-box ts-float-left ">
    <div class="tshowcase-box-info ts-align-left  ">
        <div class="tshowcase-box-title">FULL NAME</div>
        <div class="tshowcase-box-details">
            <div class="tshowcase-single-position"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>JOB TITLE</div>
            <div class="tshowcase-single-telephone"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i><a href="tel:PHONE">PHONE</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tshowcase-box-social"><a href="mailto:EMAIL" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg"></i></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a public url this relates to? Do you want only the first match (is there only one match per page?) of full name etc...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a loop over each listing you can test if present and act accordingly

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

html = '''
<div class="tshowcase-inner-box ts-float-left ">
    <div class="tshowcase-box-info ts-align-left  ">
        <div class="tshowcase-box-title">FULL NAME</div>
        <div class="tshowcase-box-details">
            <div class="tshowcase-single-position"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>JOB TITLE</div>
            <div class="tshowcase-single-telephone"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i><a href="tel:PHONE">PHONE</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tshowcase-box-social"><a href="mailto:EMAIL" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg"></i></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tshowcase-inner-box ts-float-left ">
    <div class="tshowcase-box-info ts-align-left  ">
        <div class="tshowcase-box-title">FULL NAME2</div>
        <div class="tshowcase-box-details">
            <div class="tshowcase-single-position"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>JOB TITLE2</div>
            <div class="tshowcase-single-telephone"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i><a href="tel:PHONE">PHONE2</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tshowcase-box-social"><a href="mailto:EMAIL2" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg"></i></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
results = []

for listing in soup.select('.tshowcase-inner-box'):
    name = listing.select_one('.tshowcase-box-title')
    job = listing.select_one('.tshowcase-single-position')
    tel = listing.select_one('.tshowcase-single-telephone')
    email = listing.select_one('[href^=mailto]')
    if name is None:
        name = 'Not present'
    else:
        name = name.text
    if job is None:
        job = 'Not present'
    else:
        job = job.text
    if tel is None:
        tel = 'Not present'
    else:
        tel = tel.text
    if email is None:
        email = 'Not present'
    else:
        email = email['href'].replace('mailto:','')
    results.append({ 'name' : name, 'job' : job, 'tel': tel, 'email': email })
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `soup.find_all` to locate the elements, and then access the `text` and `href` values:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
d = soup(html, 'html.parser')
s = [i.text for i in d.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile('title$|position$|telephone$')})]
result = [*s, d.find('div', {'class':'tshowcase-box-social'}).a['href'][7:]]
```

Output:

```
['FULL NAME', 'JOB TITLE', 'PHONE', 'EMAIL']
```

---

If you are trying to scrape multiple contact blocks on the page, you can convert the code above into a function that accepts a `bs4` object to scrape a single listing and iterate over all the block `div`s:

```
def get_contact(d):
   s = [i.text for i in d.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile('title$|position$|telephone$')})]
   return [*s, d.find('div', {'class':'tshowcase-box-social'}).a['href'][7:]]

results = [get_contact(i) for i in soup(html, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'tshowcase-inner-box'})]
```

Output:

```
[['FULL NAME', 'JOB TITLE', 'PHONE', 'EMAIL']]
```

Comment: I think I follow what you're doing, but I'm getting an error: `results = [get_contact(i) for i in soup(html, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'tshowcase-inner-box'})]
  File "python3.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.7.1-py3.7.egg/bs4/element.py", line 1620, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key`

Comment: @NicoleC.Baratta I suggest upgrading `BeautifulSoup`: `pip install beautifulsoup4 --upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

My version of getting the contact information:

```
data = '''<div class="tshowcase-inner-box ts-float-left ">
    <div class="tshowcase-box-info ts-align-left  ">
        <div class="tshowcase-box-title">FULL NAME</div>
        <div class="tshowcase-box-details">
            <div class="tshowcase-single-position"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>JOB TITLE</div>
            <div class="tshowcase-single-telephone"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i><a href="tel:PHONE">PHONE</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tshowcase-box-social"><a href="mailto:EMAIL" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg"></i></a></div>
    </div>
</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

data = []
for div in soup.select('.tshowcase-inner-box'):
    data.append([])
    data[-1].extend(txt.strip() for txt in div.get_text(separator='|').split('|') if txt.strip())
    data[-1].extend(a['href'].replace('mailto:', '') for a in div.select('a[href*="mailto:"]'))

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
[['FULL NAME', 'JOB TITLE', 'PHONE', 'EMAIL']]
```